# Alternative proof of existence of infinitely many positive integers not of the form $2ij+i+j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, alternative-proof

It is relatively easy to prove that there exist infinitely many positive integers not of the form $2ij+i+j$, where $i,j\in \mathbb N$.

Sundaram already found that some positive integer is prime if and only if it is of the form $2k+1$, were $k$ is some positive integer not of the form $2ij+i+j$. The proof is pretty straightforward, as $2(2ij+i+j)+1=(2i+1)(2j+1)$. And as we have many proofs of the existence of infinitely many prime numbers, we can use any of them together with Sundaram's result to prove the existence of infinitely many positive integers not of the form $2ij+i+j$.

**My question**

Do you know of / can you share any proof of the existence of infinitely many positive integers not of the form $2ij+i+j$ that does not use neither Sundaram's result nor some classical proofs of the existence of infinitely many prime numbers? For instance, a proof using sieve theory would be acceptable.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

As a clarification, I am not looking for alternative proofs that there are infinitely many primes. I am looking for a proof that there are infinitely many positive integers not of the form $2ij+i+j$, because maybe it can be useful to derive insights for the generalized form $Kij+i+j$, $K\in\mathbb N$. Incidentally, the fact that there are infinitely many primes tell us (through Sundaram's) that there are infinitely many positive integers not of the form $2ij+i+j$, but I have not been able to extrapolate something useful for the generalized problem.

Comment: What is the smallest number which can't be written this way?

Comment: The first 4000 numbers can be written in the form 2ij+i+j. That removes a lot of alternative proof candidates.. Even if an alternative proof is possible, my guess is that it will be significantly more complicated than relating to the infinitude of the primes and the algebraic expansion.

Comment: This is [A005097](https://oeis.org/A005097), and that page gives several interpretations (including the one connected to primes).

Comment: @Snared maybe I am missing something, but for instance $1,2,3$ can not be written in the form $2ij+i+j$. Take into account that $i,j\in\mathbb N$

Comment: @Snared  What do you mean?  The least number that is so expressible is $F(1,1)=4$, so $1,2,3$ can't be so written.  Then $F(2,1)=F(1,2)$ is next and that's $7$, so neither $5$ nor $6$ is so expressible.  Indeed, as the OP argues, $k$ is inexpressible iff $2k+1$ is prime.  Of course, we are asked to not use the equivalence is arguing the infinitide.

Comment: yup I messed up my script, I see now. I had j=0 so was getting everything back

Comment: Usual problem: in some countries (including mine), $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$, and "positive" includes $0$ too.

Comment: This is essentially a sieve issue.  Fixing $i=1$ gives the sequences $\{4, 7, 10, 13, \cdots\}$, i.e. $n\equiv 1 \pmod 3$, starting at $4$.  Similarly, $i=2$ gives $n\equiv 2\pmod 5$, starting at $7$, and so on.  Look at the progressions generated this way  and try to argue that the first term grows too fast to allow the progressions to cover everything.  The starting terms are  $\{4, 7, 10, 13, \cdots\}$ so, again, the integers $n\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ starting at $4$.  Not sure this will work without knowing that there are infinitely many primes, though.

Comment: It is unclear what sort of proof would be acceptable to OP.  What would it mean to not use the existence of infinitely many prime numbers, to prove something that is plainly equivalent to the existence of infinitely many (odd) prime numbers?

Comment: For instance, a proof in the line of the sketch proposed by @Lulu would be acceptable

Comment: @ErickWong I have edited the OP to clarify your point, if you find it ok we can delete our comments. Thanks for your help to improve the post!

Comment: I would not have an idea how to prove this without using that there are infinite many primes , a fact which is easy enough to prove. If you are looking for alternative proofs of this fact , I think this approach is not good.

Comment: @Peter I am not looking for alternative proofs that there are infinitely many primes. I am looking for a proof that there are infinitely many positive integers not of the form $2ij+i+j$, because maybe it can be useful to derive insights for the generalized form $Kij+i+j$, $K\in \mathbb N$. Incidentally, the fact that there are infinitely many primes tell us (through Sundaram's) that there are infinitely many numbers not of the form $2ij+i+j$, but I can not extrapolate for the generalized problem. I will edit the OP to clarify this point